# create m3u8 with multi isolate ts

Tags: video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8, mpeg2-ts

I have a demand which record a mp4 every 3 seconds(the mp4 files are continuous).
And with ffmpeg I convert the mp4 file to ts file after every 3s mp4 generated. 
So now I have many 3s ts files(the ts files are continuous, and play in player). 
Then I generate a m3u8 file, which have information about these ts files.
Everything looks fine now, but when I use a player play the m3u8 file, always block after first ts file played.

I think there must be some relationship between ts files in m3u8(maybe timestamp?) and mine don't have these relationship so my m3u8 block after first ts file played.

I don't know much about ts and m3u8, can anyone tell me what's the relationship between ts files in m3u8, or how can I generate correct m3u8 file?

Comment: Time stamps and continuity counters must be preserved across ts.

Answer (score 0):

What does your m3u8 file look like?
Something like this?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://example.com/path/to/resource.mp4/crypt.key?id=somekey"
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:6.000,
http://example.com/path/to/resource.mp4/segment1_0_a.ts
#EXTINF:6.000,
http://example.com/path/to/resource.mp4/segment2_0_a.ts
#EXTINF:6.000,
http://example.com/path/to/resource.mp4/segment3_0_a.ts
#EXTINF:1.992,
http://example.com/path/to/resource.mp4/segment4_0_a.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

When in doubt, read the documentation: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23#section-3